# Switch or Routes? Which is it with React Router?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I cannot use "Switch" or "Routes" with react router (specifically **react-router-dom**). Because there seems to be a bit of confusion about which one to use, **Switch** or **Routes**, I decided to try both to get try to get somewhere.

I am using react-router-dom version :

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
```

If I import like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
```

compiler says that **`Cannot resolve symbol 'Routes'`**

If I instead import Switch like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
```

then I get this error **`export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'`**

Is this some bug in the version?

********** UPDATE ***********

I have rolled back to React Router/Dom version 5.2.0.

Version 6.x seems too broken.

For example in the @type module installing version 6.x installs the wrong types.

```
"name": "@types/react-router",
"version": "5.1.17",
```

This is wrong and confuses my IDE.

Answer (score 12):

This is not a bug. It's about react router version. Since version 6 is completely different from version 5 and uses **Routes** instead of **Switches**. You can still make your code work by downgrading to version 5 or if you want to work with the new version, follow the migration plan:

[Upgrading from V5 to V6 react router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

You need to upgrade all *Switch tag* elements to *Route tag* elements in V6 according to docs.

V5 code example:

```js
    // This is a React Router v5 app
    import {
      BrowserRouter,
      Switch,
      Route,
      Link,
      useRouteMatch
    } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
              <Users />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
```

This is the same app in v6:

```js
// This is a React Router v6 app
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bug in the version. The `Routes` component in v6 effectively replaced the `Switch` component from v5. v6.2.1 is the current version and after just checking it in a codesandbox it imports a `Routes` component without issue.

Try uninstalling `react-router-dom` and reinstalling it. Ensure you kill any development code watchers/hot reloaders.

```
npm uninstall -s react-router-dom react-router
npm install -s react-router-dom@latest
```

Then restart your development build.

```
npm start
```

Comment: nope. it still does not recognise "Routes". The problem seems to be that react-router for some reason installs version 5.x in the @types module, instead of 6.x thoroughly confusing my IDE. I do not know if i should delete this types module.

Comment: @OliverWatkins That's interesting. When I use `react-router-dom` in a codesandbox repo it seems to only pull the v6 typings, though I don't know if CSB uses *actual* typescript or if it's just using static code analysis similar to intellisense. Yeah, I don't [definitely typed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom) updated just yet.