# Route info not showing on page

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to develop a web using react but I'm facing a problem which I can't tell the scorce of
for some reason the content in my pages is not exported, and my header component is missing too(only with the the page routes).

here is my code:

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import CoinPage from './pages/CoinPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Route path='/' component={HomePage} exact/>
      <Route path='/coins/:id' component={CoinPage}/>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

coinPage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const CoinPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    CoinPage
    </div>
  )
}

export default CoinPage
```

HomePage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    HomePage
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

Header.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    Header
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a codesandbox

Comment: You should wrap your `Route`s with a `Switch` or `Routes` component (that must be direct child of `BrowserRouter`, so remove the div wrapping your `Route`s), depending on the version of `react-router-dom`. Take a look at [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70664561/13181643) showing how to structure the router for both versions.

Comment: what is your react-router-dom version

Comment: I uninstalled the react-router-dom and downloaded the latest version again, tried wraping with both Switch and Routes but still nothing );